# SQL - XML PATH(''=

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

I need help to concatenate three tables:

```
Table1               Table 2 (Rel)                Table 3
ID   Desc            IDTable1   IDTable3          ID      Descr  
1    desc1               1          1             1        Nome1
2    desc2               2          1             2        Nome2
3    desc3               3          1
                         1          2
                         3          2
```

The result is the following:

```
New Table
    CName        Cname2
    Nome1           desc1,desc2,desc3
    Nome2           desc1,desc3
```

I tried in this way:

```
Select t3.descr,
    STUFF((SELECT '\n' + t1.desc  as [text()] from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.idtable1
    inner join Table3 t3 on t3.ID = t2.IDTable3 order by t1.Desc FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) AS Cname2 
from  Table3 t3 inner join Table2 t2 on t3.ID = t2.IDTable3
where IDTable1 = '9A02C9C1-76B9-E711-A964-005056B10019'
group by t3.descr
```

I tried that but the result is the following:

```
New Table
    CName        Cname2
    Nome1           desc1,desc2,desc3,desc1,desc3
    Nome2           desc1,desc2,desc3,desc1,desc3
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `t3` alias twice in your solution, and therefore, your subquery is not dependent on the outer query. That is the reason why you have the same list of values for both `Descr` values. I guess you want it something like this:

```
Select t3.descr,
    STUFF(
      (SELECT '\n' + t1.desc  as [text()] 
       from Table1 t1 
       inner join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.idtable1
       where t3.ID = t2.IDTable3 
       order by t1.Desc 
       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) AS Cname2 
from  Table3 t3 
inner join Table2 t2 on t3.ID = t2.IDTable3
where IDTable1 = '9A02C9C1-76B9-E711-A964-005056B10019' 
group by t3.ID, t3.descr
```

I have added the `t3.ID` into your `GROUP BY` so it can be used in the subquery.